# Saving and loading data in an offline application

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, client-side

I'm working on a strictly client side, cross platform application using web design that will allow the user to input data such as vendor and product information but when I use various methods in javascript I can't save or load data to a local file. What can I use to either get around issues with XMLHttpRequests or what are some methods that don't even use XMLHttpRequests?

Comment: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/localforage-offline-storage-improved/

Comment: Do you want this data to persist, even after running a _cleaner_ like CCleaner?

Comment: Yes, basically saving data in a .xml/.json file in a sibling folder.

Comment: Ok, and what do you mean by a "cross platform application"?

Comment: I'm building on a Linux for a friend with a Mac. Essentially any os, any browser.

Comment: Then I recommend to search the web for "cross platform offline web application", as that type of question is to broad to post here